# How to call the alert message from the partial view using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a action method Save() to save my form data, And I wants to show the exceptions occurred at run time in an Alert Message with an alert type as Error.

I have created an Error Model and also a partial View to Redirect and Render the Errors.

But Exceptions are not appeared in alert box. How do I write a common action to show all Type of my Exceptions? Could any one pls assist.

And here is my Code:

Jquert That calls Save action:

```
    $("#save-icon").click(function (event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         if ($('#Code').val() != '' && $('#Name').val() != '') {
             $.post('@Url.Action("Save")', $("#form1").serialize());
         }
     });
```

Save Action:

```
    public override ActionResult Save()
    {
        try
        {
            ....
            regionClient.Save(ct);
            return Json(new { result = ct });
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ShowError", new { ErrType="I", ErrMessage=Ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

ShowError Action:

```
    public ActionResult ShowError(string ErrType,string ErrMessage)
    {
        Error Err = new Error(ErrType, ErrMessage);
        return PartialView(Err);
    }
```

Error Model:

public class Error
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }

```
    public Error(string ErrType, string ErrMessage)
    {
        Type = ErrType;
        Message = ErrMessage;
    }
}
```

And A Partial View:

```
@model iBoxV5.Models.Error
@section Scripts
{
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var message='@Model.Message';
      alert("Error:"+message);
    });
}
```

Thanks in Advance.. Happy Coding!

Comment: if the error display you want is for jquery only , use `http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/` for that.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to do it this way, because `$.post` is AJAX request, you have to return error message, e.g. in `JSON` format and alert it from within your `$.post`:

```
$("#save-icon").click(function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     if ($('#Code').val() != '' && $('#Name').val() != '') {
         $.post('@Url.Action("Save")', $("#form1").serialize(), function(data) {
             if(data.type == 'error') {
                 alert(data.result);
             }
         });
     }
 });
```

Your action method could be something like this:

```
public override ActionResult Save()
{
    try
    {
        // ....
        regionClient.Save(ct);
        return Json(new { type="success", result = ct });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Json(new { type="error", result = e.Message });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to display the error in alert-box when some exception occurs in ajax calls. If I'm correct you can follow this.

The built-in error handling mechanism of the ASP.NET MVC always returns an error view (`Error`) located in the shared folder whenever some exception occurs in normal requests as well as in AJAX requests. The `Error` view also not displays the exception it just displays a plain text. Although it's not a good idea to display the errors directly to the user if you still want to show the errors in the `Error` view you could do like this.

**Shared/Error.cshtml**

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

<h2>Exception details</h2>
<p>
    Controller: @Model.ControllerName <br>
    Action: @Model.ActionName
    Exception: @Model.Exception
</p>
```

You have to strongly type the `Error` view to `HandleErrorInfo` model to show the exception message in the view.

When come back to the ajax calls instead of returning `Error` view it will be a good idea to return a `JSON` object that contains the error details. For that you have to create a `custom handle error filter` as described below,

```
public class CustomHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    private readonly ILog _logger;
 
    public CustomHandleErrorAttribute()
    {
        _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("MyLogger");
    }
 
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled || !filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
        {
            return;
        }
 
        if (new HttpException(null, filterContext.Exception).GetHttpCode() != 500)
        {
            return;
        }
 
        if (!ExceptionType.IsInstanceOfType(filterContext.Exception))
        {
            return;
        }
 
        // if the request is AJAX return JSON else view.
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
        {
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult 
            { 
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet, 
                Data = new
                { 
                    error = true,
                    message = filterContext.Exception.Message
                } 
            };
        }
        else
        {
            var controllerName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
            var actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
            var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName);
             
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
            {
                ViewName = View,
                MasterName = Master,
                ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model),
                TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
            };
        }
 
        // log the error using log4net.
        _logger.Error(filterContext.Exception.Message, filterContext.Exception);
 
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
 
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;      
    }
}
```

You have to replace the `HandleErrorAttribute` registered in the `Global.asax.cs` to the `CustomHandleErrorAttribute` and you are done. Now you get a JSON object in the case if exceptions that occured in AJAX calls which contains the exception details.

For more information about exception handling please refer this [post](http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/5/exception_handling_in_asp_net_mvc).